Why do I get the same first byte in the key when using PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA512 while generating a 64 byte key from two different passwords?
StackExchange,
I was experimenting out some C++ code using OpenSSL libraries to generate a 64 byte key from a password using: PBKDF2 with HMAC and SHA512 to generate a 64 byte key, and I was a bit perplexed to see that two different passwords generated a key that had the same first byte.
How is that possible? Where is the "avalange effect"?
To replicate the issue, I re-implemented the same in Python so you can experiment out the code quickly and find out what's wrong with it.
It turns out there is no issue with the C++ code, because the Python code below also produced the same output.
import hashlib
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac

# The number of iterations is same for deriving key from any password... 
ITERATIONS = 2000
# The required key length. 
REQ_KEY_LEN = 64

passwords = ["FirstPassword", "SecondPassword"]

for passwd in passwords:
    # Generating the key for each password in the list. 
    key = pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', passwd.encode("ascii"), b"", ITERATIONS, REQ_KEY_LEN)
    
    # Printing the key in hexadecimal format. 
    print(f"Derived key: {key.hex()}")


Running the above code produced the following output:
Derived key: c423449f5b8d051b3bf8fb26f3bec0928978c6bb179d1ecc8233337f5d195f4792153d332d5bc92624b080ac1e57c20c4d5c908bead3095319f8107489ebae92
Derived key: c480e31e57f47b236bdb1a795d12e51f2ce6c046f850bc5e7096edb2022f0db8b9d88b7cf8456638ee2bcec9c0f750164535065b8d05adae0707c984b41e91fa

NOTE: This is the same output I also got from the C++ code that used the latest version of OpenSSL libraries, when I compiled and ran it and which caused me to investigate further into this issue!
Notice, that the first byte in the derived key (0xc4) is same!
Why didn't the avalange affect change atleast one bit of the common byte in this case?
Is there something inside HMAC or PBKDF-2 that is the causing the issue?
Did I miss anything?
Thankyou very much :)

It's just chance -- it will happen for any pair of inputs with probability 1/256. If you change iterations to 10k (still far too low for actual password security) you get outputs starting with different bytes; you also do for "PasswordOne" and "PasswordTwo" or "MyPassword" and "YourPassword" (at either 2k or 10k). And PBKDF2 is deterministic, so yes all correct implementations given the same input produce the same output.

@dave_thompson_085 Thankyou very much for the reply :) Please feel free to answer the question. In practise I will definitely use an iteration count like 1 million. But, this could have been avoided even with low iteration count, if a salt was used. But in my case I cannot use a salt.
